# error: void value not ignored as it ought to be , how can I solve this issue?

Tags: c, binary-search-tree, modified-preorder-tree-t

```
void preorderTraversal(struct node*tree)
{

    if (tree != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d", tree->data);
        tree->left=preorderTraversal(tree->left);
        tree->right = preorderTraversal(tree->right);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 3):

Function `preorderTraversal` is declared `void`.

That is, it does not *return* any value.

But on these lines:

```
tree->left = preorderTraversal(tree->left);
tree->right = preorderTraversal(tree->right);
```

You are treating it as if it returns a value that can be assigned to `->left` and `->right`